# Looking for a manhua where the MC ends up joining a secret/forbidden sect or society, helps him earn points. Ends up get caught and changed his face

Tags: story-identification, manga, cultivation

I don’t remember much about the beginning but it started out as a normal cultivation manhua where the MC was in a sect.

He somehow gets this opportunity to join a forbidden society/sect where he does missions to get points within the forbidden sect. He can redeem those points for pills and stuff for his own cultivation.

That society is forbidden, and if you are associated with it, you get killed or something. After a while this dragon, or a big lizard, realizes he is part of that society and tries to kill him. He runs and gets injured. He later changed his whole appearance and went to a new country or continent.